# Showing a basic inequality but couldn't figure out a step

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $4{p_2}^2+9{p_3}^2-{p_1}^2 \leq 0 $ and $4{q_2}^2+9{q_3}^2-{q_1}^2 \leq 0 $, I'm trying to show that $ 4{p_2}{q_2}+9{p_3}{q_3}-{p_1}{q_2} \leq 0$  (where al $q$ and $p$ s are real numbers and nonnegative). I got $2p_2 \leq p_1$ and $2q_2 \leq q_1$ from taking the square roots of the given inequalities and,
$ \sqrt { 4{p_2}^2+9{p_3}^2} \leq \sqrt {{p_1}^2 } $ and as $p_1 \geq 0$, so $2p_2 \leq \sqrt { 4{p_2}^2+9{p_3}^2} \leq p_1$ And similarly, $2q_2 \leq q_1$ in the same manner. I got $3p_3 \leq p_1$  and $3q_3 \leq q_1$. I have multiplied the first two inequalities side by side then I obtained $4p_2{q_2} \leq p_1{q_1}$. Similarly, having multiplied the other two obtained inequalities side by side, I got $9p_3{q_3} \leq p_1{q_1}$. The sum of the last two derived inequalites gives me $ 4{p_2}{q_2}+9{p_3}{q_3} \leq 2{p_1}{q_1} $. I need to show $2p_2 \leq \frac{1}{k} p_1$, $2q_2 \leq \frac{1}{k} q_1$, for some positive integer $k$. However, I couldn't find any further manipulation. I'm open to any insight for this relatively easy question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry for that typo. I meant to say $ 4{p_2}{q_2}+9{p_3}{q_3}-{p_1}{q_2} \leq 0$ .

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry again, you guessed right, I should have written $2p_1{q_1}$. I tried to say that I multiplied $2q_2 \leq q_1$ by $2p_2 \leq p_1$ and $3q_3 \leq q_1$ by  $3p_3 \leq p_1$ and got $4q_2{p_2} \leq p_1{q_1}$, $3q_3{p_3} \leq p_1{q_1}$. I added the last two inequalities side by side, and got $4q_2{p_2} +9q_3{p_3}  \leq 2p_1{q_1}$.

Comment: this is Cauchy Schwarz with the 4,9 part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a square symmetric positive definite matrix $A,$ we get Cauchy Schwarz.

Here,
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and we have column vectors $p$ and $q,$ each with subscripts 2,3 only.

$$
p =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_2 \\
p_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
q =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
q_2 \\
q_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Note that $p^T Aq$ is 1 by 1, therefore equals its own transpose, and $p^TAq  = q^T Ap.$

With **every** real $s$

$$ (sp - q)^T A (sp - q) \geq 0 $$
$$ (p^TAp)s^2 - 2 (p^T A q)s + (q^T A q) \geq 0.  $$
As this is nonnegative **for all real** $s,$ the discriminant is nonpositive,
$$ 4 (p^TAq)^2 - 4 (p^TAp)(q^T A q) \leq 0 $$
$$ (p^T A q)^2 \leq (p^TAp)(q^T A q) $$ 
$$ p^T A q \leq \sqrt{p^TAp} \sqrt{q^T A q} $$

$$  4 p_2 q_2 + 9 p_3 q_3 = p^T A q \leq \sqrt{4 p_2^2 + 9 p_3^2}  \sqrt{4 q_2^2 + 9 q_3^2} \leq p_1 q_1 $$